# Have to click twice to toggle .click() Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, click

I know there are similar questions but there was none which could help me yet.
I want to toggle the CSS "transform" property for the `.fa-caret-right` Element. When I click the first time, the function works well. But when I try to trigger it second time, I always have to click twice.
I have separated the JavaScript and HTML code in different files, and linked it in the `head` of the HTML file.

**Edit**: I added `#counter` and found out, that `count++;` is *always* working when `fa-caret-right` is clicked but `transform` is only working *every other time*.

Maybe someone sees a mistake I made, thank you!
I already tried several click events I know, but this is my code at the moment:

HTML (there is a total of 13 `#p` elements)

```
<section class="viewport">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="controls">
         <i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>
      <p id="counter">1 of 13</p>
      <div class="gallery large">
        <img src="files/img/ogimage.jpg" id="p1">
        <img src="files/img/ogimage2.jpg" id="p2">
        <img src="files/img/ogimage3.jpg" id="p3">
        <img src="files/img/ogimage4.jpg" id="p4">
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

JavaScript

```
//JavaScript Document
$('document').ready(function() {

  var count = 1;
  var total = 13;

  $('.fa-caret-right').on('click' ,function scrollHorizontal() {
      count++;

      var number = count + " of 13";
      var scrollTo = $("#p"+count);
      var where = $(scrollTo).offset().left - 150;

      $('#counter').html(number);

      $(".gallery").stop().css("transform","translateX(-"+where+"px)");
    }
 );

});
```

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle or codepen for this problem?

Comment: You are using ```count``` for tracking. When you click once, ```count=2``` which means ```p2``` but when you click it again  it becomes 3 and ```p3``` is not there. Also for it working for the third click the reason could be it is reloading the page or initiating the ```$("document").ready``` function which makes ```count=1``` again.

Comment: Actually there are 13 `#p` elements - I shortened the code in this example. 
If you are right, that the page is reloaded, it is not visible for me. I also tried to write the code without `$("document").ready` but then nothing works.

But I inserted an counter in the document and realized, that `count` is always increased whereas the CSS-action is not working. So the function is partially working.

Comment: you will surely need ```$("document").ready``` as it executes you jquery after loading it. Else you cannot use ```$``` if jquery is loading slow. Did you tried the answer mentioned by derek. If possible please share some fiddle or ```codepen``` that would be useful. Try using ```debugger``` to check the value of variables at different step.

Comment: @Jack in JSFiddle it "scrolls" at every click, but one time more than at the other, so it still isn't really working.
[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marlinprauss/kcx2x92m/)

Answer (score 0):

Move var count=1 outside (above)  $(‘document’).ready()

Comment: Nice idea, but unfortunately did not solve the problem. 
I just inserted an counter in the document and realized, that `count` is always increased whereas the CSS-action is not working. So the function is partially working... Do you still have an idea for a solution?